# "なんてこったい こりゃいったい" is this some kind of slang?

Tags: slang

I've come across something and always wondered about it, what is the meaning of

> "なんてこったいこりゃいったい"?

I assume (but I'm not quite sure) that it's this: to show disbelief or surprise

Also, is this something actually used? (and if it is, in what context?)

Answer (score 7):

> なんてこったいこりゃいったい

is a colloquial, slurred pronunciation of 「なんてことだい、これはいったい」

which is a reversed version (倒置) of 「これはいったい、なんてことだい？」

To break it down...

なんて  -- pronoun [何]{なん} + case particle (っ)て; ≂「なんという」
こったい  -- noun こと (事) + copula だ + sentence ending particle い (≂よ)
こりゃ -- pronoun これ + particle は
いったい -- noun 一体 (used for emphasis in questions; "on earth")

So it *literally* means... "What kind of thing on earth is this?" "What on earth is the matter?" -- used as an exclamation, like "What the hell is this?"

Comment: By the way the phrase sounds a bit funny to me cos こ**ったい** is rhyming with い**ったい** ... なんか冗談みたいで滑稽な感じ？

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but there your text has two parts:

> なんてこった （い）

which is an exclamation that roughly translates to "oh no", and

> こりゃいったい

which means "just what (is this)...".