# Is やなこった just 嫌な子, or does it mean something as a whole?

Tags: translation, meaning, expressions, manga

Another phrase from 犬夜叉 that is puzzling me is やなこった. Apparently it means something as there is a quite lot of results on the [interwebz](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22%E3%82%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%93%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%22). They are not much of a help though.

I saw it in a comic, where a character explains that he wants to fight alone without a girl that has been only a nuisance. So I though that it would be something like 嫌な子. The common usage together with the った confuses me though.

Is it possible that this mean something en bloc? If that’s not the case, what is the meaning of that った? I guess it can be something like: „I have already said that the girl is only a nuisance“ But I am not sure.

[image: 犬夜叉]

Comment: Can u link the source or an image of the comic in question?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Sure! Added to the question. Spamming with Inuyasha.

Comment: https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%93%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F first result on google

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/53586/%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a6%e3%81%93%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84-%e3%81%93%e3%82%8a%e3%82%83%e3%81%84%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84-is-this-some-kind-of-slang

Comment: I wonder how could I miss the entry on Weblio. Hopefully better luck next time. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

やなこった is a slang term that means "no way" (as in "no way Jose"). As pointed out in a comment, this is etymologically a contracted/emphasized pronunciation of 嫌なことだ.

In my opinion, this word form is no longer "alive" in my generation unless in a jestful manner. It's a typical older Tokyo inner city dialect ([下町言葉](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B1%9F%E6%88%B8%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89)) that is, today, mostly used by some fictional characters (like 犬夜叉, who generally carries the trait). Or you can see it living in especially early volumes of Doraemon etc.